# jQuery.data() returns 'undefined' when retrieving data from dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

My case is very simple, I just tried to store data into an element which `appended` in the `DOM` dynamically. My problem is, whenever I tried to retrieve the data through the immediate `appended object`, the value is returning fine, but through the object returned from the `click` event through `on` function it is returning `undefined`. I searched about this earlier, but people in stackoverflow were just suggested about removing the camel casing etc. That did not help me out in my case. Any suggestions or fix will be more helpful.

**My code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    xElement = $('<li class="test">click this (because this contains data)</li>').appendTo('ul');

    jQuery.data(xElement,"val","value1");

    alert(jQuery.data(xElement,'val'));

    $(document).on('click','ul li',function(){ alert(jQuery.data($(this),'val')); });
     });
```

**A Fiddle :**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qaFwQ/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yYzqP/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.data()` takes a raw DOM element, not a jQuery object.

You need to either pass `this` directly, or call the instance method (`$(this).data()`)

Comment: Mr.SLaks Thanks for your valuable info. `You need to either pass this directly` can you give an example for this.?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    xElement = $('<li class="test">click this (because this contains data)</li>').appendTo('ul');
    xElement.data("val","value1");
    //retrieving data from immediate object
    alert(xElement.data('val'));
    $(document).on('click','ul li',function(){ 
        //retrieving data through object from 'on'
        alert($(this).data('val')); 
    });
});
```

Very strange, but if you do it this way, it seems to work fine.

[FIDDLEMETHIS](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/yYzqP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DevlshOne, this was starting to cause me a bit of a headache - I cant vote you up or comment as I dont have enough reputation.

But if anyone is working with datatables this solves the problem of any hidden values (as the default table only shows 1- 10 ) and you can not access the data attr from 11 + as they get dynamically generated afterwards.

old code

`$('.userId').on('click', function(){
  var userId = $(this).data('id');`

new code

`$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
  var userId = $(this).data('id');`

Thanks